# WebServlet annotation not working in production (works in development)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am using Google App Engine STANDARD (SDK 1.9.62) and have set my appengine-web.xml to use java8 runtime and trying to get a simple [servlet example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/requests/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/requests/RequestsServlet.java).  Works as expected in local dev server but gives me a 404 error in the google cloud.  I WANT to use the Google App Engine standard environment (not flex).  Is there a yaml entry or xml entry I need to turn on for this to work?  How can I be sure that GAE is using the 3.1 servlet spec and not 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Mystery solved.  I had two versions running in deployment and an original java7, servlet 2.5 api version was handling all traffic.  My INTENDED version, which was a java8, servlet 3.x was sitting idle and getting 0% traffic.  Once I used the version migration function in google's cloud console, the servlets annotated with servlet 3.x annotations started working.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine Standard uses [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref), whereas Flexible uses [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml).

Now, this Java-docs-sample us using the [pom.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/requests/pom.xml) to set dependencies. you can see the versions of the dependencies set there.

In this case, that sample can be deployed with mvn appengine:deploy and the endpoint serving in App Engine would be /requests. i.e https://project-name.appspot.com/requests which should return a "hello, world"

Comment: I appreciate the effort but neither the local deployment or the deployment to GAE work with the "requests" sub-project.  mvn puked all over the place with `Unable to stage:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.`